# How to evaluate this integral step by step?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate

$$\int\int\sin(x-y)dxdy$$

Is it difficult?

see: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+int+sin%28x-y%29+dx+dy

Comment: What is the range of integral?

Comment: @gaoxinge - Give all possible answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \int \sin(x-y)dxdy = \int (c_1(y)-\cos(x-y))dy = \int (c_1(y)-\cos(y-x))dy$$
The first equality is just indefinite integration (there's an implicit $u$ substitution being used, $u=x-y$, but since $y$ is held fixed in the integration, $du=dx$.) The "constant" $c(y)$ shows up because the derivative of any function of $y$ - with respect to $x$ - is $0$. The second equality follows because $\cos$ is even.

$$\int (c_1(y)-\cos(y-x))dy = \int c_1(y)dy - \sin(y-x)+c_2(x)$$
Again, this is just the indefinite integral of what we know we can integrate, and we get another . Since $c(y)$ is an arbitrary function of $y$ (not necessarily even continuous, though for convenience I assume integrable), we can't write what its integral is. So your solution is

$$\int \int \sin(x-y)dxdy = C_1(y) - \sin(y-x)+c_2(x)$$ for some differentiable function $C_1(y)$ and some function $c_2(x)$.

Comment: How come wolfram alpha show a different result?

Comment: Because it's ignoring the $y$ altogether when integrating with respect to $x$.